# Solving poisson's equation with boundary conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

I am Gopal Koya.I have a problem in solving a PDE that is needed in my research work. I need to solve a laplace equation with the boundary conditions as shown in the image that is attached to this post. I seek help in solving this.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This can in principle be solved easily using my answer to [Poisson solver using Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11768/245), especially since that code was intended to be used with visual representations of the boundary conditions and inhomogeneities. So I'll illustrate that here. I am using the terminology from electrostatics, but I hope the analogies are clear. The `conductor` shape is the boundary on which Dirichlet boundary conditions are enforced. The inhomogeneous term in your equation is a constant which I incorporate in the variable `chargePlus`. There is no need to worry about the absolute quantitative size of the terms because your equation can be rescaled to whatever length scales are needed, and similarly the function $\phi$ can be rescaled arbitrarily by choosing appropriate units for the inhomogeneous term.

*First execute the code in the linked answer above.*

```
conductors = 
 Graphics[{{GrayLevel[.5], 
    Rectangle[1.1 {-1, -1}, 1.1 {1, 1}]}, {Black, 
    Disk[{0, 0}, 1]}, {GrayLevel[.5], 
    Disk[{0, 1.1}, .9, {Pi, 2 Pi}], 
    Disk[{0, -1.1}, .9, {0, Pi}]}}, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
  ImagePadding -> None]
```

[image: batman1]

```
chargePlus = 
 Graphics[{{GrayLevel[0], 
    Rectangle[1.1 {-1, -1}, 1.1 {1, 1}]}, {GrayLevel[.5], 
    Disk[{0, 0}, 1]}, {GrayLevel[0], 
    Disk[{0, 1.1}, .9, {Pi, 2 Pi}], 
    Disk[{0, -1.1}, .9, {0, Pi}]}}, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
  ImagePadding -> None]
```

[image: batman2]

```
chargeMinus = 
  Graphics[{}, PlotRange -> (PlotRange /. FullOptions[conductors])];

susceptibility = 
  Graphics[{}, PlotRange -> (PlotRange /. FullOptions[conductors])];

Timing[potential = 
   poissonSolver[conductors, chargePlus, chargeMinus, susceptibility];]

ListPlot3D[potential, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotStyle -> {Orange, Specularity[White, 10]}]
```

[image: solution]

The variables `chargeMinus` and `susceptibility` contain empty graphics so I don't show them.  You can essentially draw any shape you like instead of the "batman" outline. I just eyeballed a rough approximation of the shape you sketched in the question.